# How to properly build apk for testers?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

As I've seen on articles, building your app as a bundle is the best option for release.
What about when you try to build for testers like using Firebase App Distribution or Testflight?

I tried using `--split-per-abi` and I only upload the `app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk`version (32-bit).

Will it cause some performance issues for 64bit phones? because I tried using `app-arm64-v8a-release.apk` (64-bit) and some users with 32-bit phone complain about the performance (crash & lags).

So is the 32-bit apk ok for testing?

Comment: It is **not** okay for testing on all phones. You should just build a fat APK and upload it, unless Firebase App distribution supports uploading multiple APKs and automatically distributes them based on device type.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is run:

`flutter build apk`

This command will create a fat package with all ABI's which you need. I don't know any issues in this approach except the app size.

For release, of course, better to use `--split-per-abi` flag or build App bundle (preferred).